# Fixed File to Object array with positions configured in xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, class, configuration

I want to convert a fixed length file to a C# object. for example I have a fixed length file like

```
Input File
------------

SAM      DENVER      20
temp     texas       33
```

This represents Name, Place, Age, Name of length 10 , Place of 10 length Age of 2 Length.

Now I am configuring my xml for the position in input file

### Configuration XML

```
<Mapping>
<Name StartPosition ="1" Length ="10"></Name>
<Place StartPosition ="11" Length ="10"></Place>
<Age StartPosition ="21" Length ="2"></Age>
</Mapping>
```

I have a class Like

### Class Object

```
public class InputFileConvertor
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Place{get;set;}
    public string Age{get;set;}

}
```

Now my question is how can I convert this input fixed length file with n number of records to string array of InputFileConvertor.
which should take all the preconfigured parameters in XML file.

Note: I want to achieve this functionality as best with less memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to load the parameter from the xml file and store them into variables like:

```
int nameStart;
int nameLenght;
int placeStart;
int placeLenght;
.....
```

After read your file:

```
List<InputFileConvertor> inputList = new ......
string[] lines =System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Data.txt");

foreach(String line in lines)
{
   InputFileConvertor lineInput = new InputFileConvertor();
   lineInput.Name = line.Substring(nameStart,nameLenght);
   //maybe remove the white spaces with String.Trim() or Regex.Replace(text,@"s","");
   //fill also the other properties

   inputList.Add(lineInput);
}
```